# Python PostgreSQL using copy_from to COPY list of objects to table

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, postgresql-copy

I'm using `Python 2.7` and `psycopg2` to connect to my DB server ( PostgreSQL 9.3 ) and I a list of objects of ( Product Class ) holds the items which i want to insert

```
products_list = []
products_list.append(product1)
products_list.append(product2)
```

And I want to use `copy_from` to insert this products list to the product table. I tried some tutorials and i had a problem with converting the products list to CSV format because the values contain single quote, new lines, tabs and double quotes. For example ( Product Description ) :

```
<div class="product_desc">
    Details :
    Product's Name : name
</div>
```

The escaping corrupted the HTML code by adding single quote before any single quote and it, So i need to use a save way to convert the list into CSV to COPY it? OR using any other way to insert the list without converting it to CSV format??

Comment: Use the Python `csv` module to do that, rather than doing it yourself. Write it to a StringIO object, then send that to the database using `copy_from`.

Comment: I did but the `csv` module corrupted my HTML.

Comment: "corrupted" how? Details? Using what settings for the module? Using what COPY options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, First of all i created a function to convert my object to csv row

```
import csv

@staticmethod
def adding_product_to_csv(item, out):
writer = csv.writer(out, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL,quotechar='"',delimiter=',',lineterminator="\r\n")
writer.writerow([item.name,item.description])
```

Then in my code i created a csv file using `Python IO` to store the data in it to `COPY` it and stored every object in the csv file using my previous function:

```
file_name = "/tmp/file.csv"
myfile = open(file_name, 'a')
for item in object_items:
    adding_product_to_csv(item, myfile)
```

Now I created the `CSV` file and it's ready to be copied using `copy_from` which exists in `psycopg2` :

```
# For some reason it needs to be closed before copying it to the table
csv_file.close()
cursor.copy_expert("COPY products(name, description) from stdin with delimiter as ',' csv QUOTE '\"' ESCAPE '\"' NULL 'null' ",open(file_name))
conn.commit()
# Clearing the file
open(file_name, 'w').close()
```

And it's working now.